# Need to capture number of lines between two search criteria

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I need to capture the number of lines between each DELETE statement.

```
DELETE FROM database.table
WHERE
@1=A
@2=B
@3=C
@4=D
@5=D
DELETE FROM database.table
WHERE
@1=A
@2=B
@3=C
@4=D
@5=D
DELETE FROM database.table
WHERE
@1=A
@2=B
@3=C
@4=D
@5=D
```

So I would get a returned status of "5"

I've tried the following:

```
awk '/DELETE/{exit}flag;/WHERE/{flag=1}' delete_statements | wc -l
```

But this only works if I delete the first line in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To skip the first line from within awk, just add the condition:

```
awk 'NR>1 && /DELETE/{exit}flag;/WHERE/{flag=1}'
     ~~~~
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
awk '/WHERE/{next} !/DELETE/{flag++} NR>1 && /DELETE/{print flag;exit}' file
```

#### Output

```
5
```